# SQL - How to select random rows until the total value of the row is a certain number?

Tags: mysql, sql

I currently have a table which has a column which holds time as an integer value. How do I select all the rows in my table in a random order until the total value of the time = a certain number e.g 10.

Comment: updated the tags to include mysql. sorry about that

Answer (score 0):

Something like this would work for SQL Server:

```
select id, timeValue from (
    select  id,
            timeValue,
            SUM(timeValue) OVER (ORDER BY CHECKSUM(NewId())) as total
    from    myTable) as subq
where   total < 10
```

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, you would use the following for the first row that meets or exceeds 10:

```
select id, timeValue from (
from (select t.*
             sum(timeValue) over (order by rand()) as running_sum
      from t
     ) t
where (running_sum - timeValue) < 10;
```

If you want rows up to *but not exceeding* 10, then:

```
where running_sum <= 10
```